# My login function not working

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am developing a C# application which need a login form , user and password are saved in a SQL Server database .

I use my `CodePass` Function to code password , I have added a user and it's coded password to my database before (user , password and login role are saved in database)

Now when i Call my doLogin function like this

```
doLogin("Arashdn","123");
```

It returns 0 ( a wrong user or password)
After debugging application I find that `hash`(a variable to keep encrypted password read from database) is holding 123 not encrypted password.

What Can the problem be?

Here is my Code:

```
public class DB
{
    public static string constr = "Server=localhost;Database=University;
    Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";
    public static string userTable = "Users", userPassword = "Passwd", 
    userName = "UserID", loginRole = "Role";
}

public class login
{
    public int doLogin(string user, string pass)
    {
        string role="0";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DB.constr);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand my_cm = conn.CreateCommand();
            SqlDataReader dbread1;
            my_cm.CommandText = "Select " + DB.userPassword + " from " + 
                DB.userTable + " WHERE " + DB.userName + "=" + user;
            dbread1 = my_cm.ExecuteReader();
            string hash="";

            while (dbread1.Read())
            {
               hash = dbread1[0].ToString();
            }

            if (CodePass(user, pass) == hash)
            {
                SqlCommand my_cm2 = conn.CreateCommand();
                SqlDataReader dbread2;
                my_cm2.CommandText = "Select " + DB.loginRole + " from " + 
                DB.userTable + " WHERE " + DB.userName + "=" + user;
                dbread2 = my_cm2.ExecuteReader();

                while (dbread2.Read())
                {
                   role = dbread2[0].ToString(); 
                }
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                    conn.Close();
        }

        return int.Parse(role);
    }

    public string CodePass(string user, string pass)
    {
        System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha = 
              new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
          sha.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(user + pass)));
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If database has password 123 and not the encrypted it is normal the result.

Comment: @kostasch. I have saved encrypted password in DB --> #<=??D?mB?MyE??C? this is what is saved in passwd cloumn in DB

Comment: so it's not `CodePass("Arashdn", "123") == "123"` ?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. So you say that CodePass(string user, string pass) does not equal with the password that you have in your database?

Comment: CodePass returns encrypted password , and password is saved encryptedly in DB but hash is keeping unecrypted password

Comment: Is it possible that your reader has more than one value? (just in case)

Comment: @WiiMaxx CodePass("Arashdn", "123") will return #<=??D?mB?MyE??C?

Comment: hash is data from your database right? So hash must be encrypted right? So hash = #<=??D?mB?MyE??C right?

Comment: @kostasch. exactly , I expect hash = #<=??D?mB?MyE??C but its 123

Comment: so the field password in your database has 123, means that dbread1[0].ToString() = 123?

Comment: The thing is not what you expect but what is in your database :)

Comment: the passwd feild in database is #<=??D?mB?MyE??C? not 123 but dbread1 is reading 123 and this is the problem

Comment: Check the number of the rows that the reader returns. Aslo get the query you run ans run it on sql.

Answer (score 2):

The likelyhood is that you have at least 2 records in the database that match the username, one with the password of "123".

From SqlManager see what the result of the following is, remember to substitute for the username:

```
select userID,passwd from Users where userId= '<put the username here>';
```

Your existing code could be rewritten to make use of SqlParameters to avoid some Sql injection attacks and also dispose of your objects properly.  Additionally most of the logic could be moved to a single database query as below.

This modification will return 0 if the user and password is incorrect.  You could throw an exception or return another value instead.

```
public class DB
{
    public static string constr = "Server=localhost;Database=University; Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";
    public static string userTable = "Users", userPassword = "Passwd", 
    userName = "UserID", loginRole = "Role";
}

public class login
{
   public int doLogin(string user, string pass)
   {
      string role="0";
      using (var conn = new SqlConnection(DB.constr) {
        using (var my_cm = conn.CreateCommand() {
         my_cm.CommandText = string.Format(
             "select {0} from {1} where {2} = @username and {3} = @password",
             DB.loginRole,
             DB.userTable,
             DB.userName,
             DB.userPassword);
         my_cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user);
         mt_cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", CodePass(user,pass));
         using (var dbread = my_cm.ExecuteReader()) {
           if (!dbread.Read()) {
             return 0; // or something else if user not found
           }
           return int.Parse(dbRead[0].ToString());
         }
      }
    }
  }

  public string CodePass(string user, string pass)
  {
    System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha = 
          new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
    return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
      sha.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(user + pass)));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on :

*`After debuging application I find that hash(a variable to keep encrypted password red from database) is holding 123 not encrypted password.`*

i would recommend to go look in your DB and change your PW in your PW field from `123` to  `#<=??D?mB?MyE??C?` because your DB only hold's the data it get's nothing more and it looks like you saved `123` instead of `#<=??D?mB?MyE??C?`

and your commend:

*`CodePass returns encrypted password , and password is saved encryptedly in DB but hash is keeping unecrypted password`*

doesn't make sense because your DB will not be able to decrypt with this query

### EDIT

if

*`the passwd feild in database is #<=??D?mB?MyE??C? not 123 but dbread1 is reading 123 and this is the problem`*

is true please check the following things:

- is it the right DataBase?
- is it the right Table?
- last but not least do you reading in the right column?

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem
I have both sql server express and developer edition on my computer and I have another database in SQLServer Developer in which passwd was 123 and my main DB was is SQLServer Express ...

Silly me